# Best way to do some async function only if condition is true before do another async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an async function which should be called no matter what.
But I want to run another async function before it if a condition is true.
But my code mess up.

```
if (needPrepare) {
    prepare(function(err, result) {
        mainJob(done);
    }
    return;
}
mainJob(done);
```

Note that both prepare and mainJob are async function.
What is the better way to write this?

Comment: You know that, if `prepare` is successful you will end up in an infinite recursion, right?

Comment: No this is not recursion. Just regular functions.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is within a function, it should be fine.  In the instance that `needPrepare == true` the `return` statement will prevent the second call to `mainJob()` from being executed at the same time as `prepare()`.  Otherwise, using an else condition will cover the two possible cases:

```
if (needPrepare) {
  prepare(function(err, result) {
    mainJob(done);
  }
}
else {
  mainJob(done);
}
```